# FXML Making a VBox invisible in the controller

Tags: user-interface, javafx, opacity, fxml, vbox

I've done some research and there doesn't seem to be any questions like this concerning the controller so here I go.
So I have wrapped some shapes in Vboxes in SceneBuilder.

```
<VBox fx:id="vStand" layoutX="403.0" layoutY="175.0" prefHeight="8.0" prefWidth="164.0" rotate="90.0">
         <children>
            <Line fx:id="stand" endX="163.0" stroke="#806565" style="-fx-opacity: 0;" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
```

You can change the opacity in here, but then the code for this not in the controller.

So I have attempted to do it through the controller. But unfortunately this does not work?

```
 @FXML
    private VBox vstand;


   @FXML 
   private void hide(ActionEvent event) {
        vstand.setOpacity(0);
   }
```

Is it because you can't assign a method to a VBox as you could with a label or button therefore meaning the action of the item being opaic is not being performed??

I should mention what I wanted to do was make the object disappear through making it opaic and the reappear by setting opacity to 100.

Although I have considered using the setVisible now I'm intrigued as to how you could get the opacity to work.

Comment: a) The fxml file uses `fx:id="vStand"`, the field is called `vstand` tough b) Where is the `hide` method used? I don't see you registering the event handler anywhere. Furthermore none of the `Node` types used in the fxml contain `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`s. If you want to trigger some kind of event, there needs to be a event that triggers the action... c) The maximum `opacity` is `1.0`, not `100`.

Comment: Are you expecting the child node (the line) to become invisible too? Calling `vstand.setVisible(false)` will hide the `VBox` and its child nodes. Calling `vstand.setOpacity(0)` will simply make the `VBox` transparent, but its child nodes will still be opaque.

Comment: Thank you for the replies they have been very useful. Since the Node types don't have events with out action triggers is their any sort of type that I could use that would store shapes/buttons that would allow me to have an event without a trigger.